# cannot resolve activitycompat and appcompatactivity

Tags: android, gradle, layout, build, appcompatactivity

PLS HELP. I think android studio Gradle files or settings got disturbed  may be when adding external jar libraries or when I tried to rename a package. Whenever I open new project or even an already finished project Im getting errors.
Even whem i open new project
BUILD FAILED in 24s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

in Mainactivity
cannot resolve activitycompat and appcompatactivity

```
    package com.example.android1.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android1.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv"/>

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
       android:id="@+id/tx01"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="go"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBjlU.png)

MainActivity Screenshot attached

[image: Layoutfile error]

Comment: have you tried in android studio File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart ?

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem with activitycompat and appcompatactivity is resolved. But the Activity layout design feature is not working @Yura

Comment: show me pls activity_main.xml

Comment: @Yura main_activity.xml added in Question now. Sorry for missing it

Comment: when you try to run a project, are you getting an error?

Comment: I been using android studio about a year, But last 2 3 days Im getting errors as described above, after trying to add external libraries and renaming package name, dont know exactly what caused it.   Apart from above Im also getting 'Mainfest merging failed due to multiple errors' randomly and goes away when I clean build and Rebuild. Pls ignore the errors in layout constraints if any,. Also now I find Error:(7, 36) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'. but buid and deployment sucessful @Yura

Comment: Also Error:External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android is not registered  , Error:(7, 36) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'.,   Error:Premature end of file.

Comment: I understand if you changed the package in a old project and something broke, but you write that when creating a new project you have an error,  in this case I would try again Invalidate Cashes and Sync project. to load dependencies,  it would be interesting if the project was uploaded and I would try to run it.

Comment: Surely, pls tell me how to do this here. Im new to this site and how to share project from Android studio

Comment: create public repository on github and drop the link to me

Comment: sorry some personal work. is there a way to chat without commenting in this @Yura